# Attempt to filter an ArrayList from another not working

Tags: java, arraylist, filtering

Attempt to filter an ArrayList from another not working

I have this ArrayList called listaGrande (Spanish for bigList). It contains objects from a class called Objeto, which has a String called loTengo (iHaveIt).

If loTengo = "Yes" or "yes", and only those words, no other, those marked Objeto should form a new ArrayList called inventario (inventory).

Here is the class that with the CONFLICTIVE method:

```
public class FiltraListas { // ListsFilter.

    public String registro; // registry.
    public ArrayList<Objeto> listaGrande;
    public ArrayList<Objeto> inventario; // CONFLICTIVE by being declared here?
    public String loTengo;
    public Objeto unObjeto; // oneObject 

    public FiltraListas(String registro) {
        this.registro = registro;
        listaGrande = new ArrayList<Objeto>();
        this.loTengo = "Yes"; 

    }

    public ArrayList<Objeto> setInventario() {
        for (Objeto cualquiera : listaGrande){ // cualquiera is Spanish for any.
            if("YES".equalsIgnoreCase(cualquiera.getLoTengo())) { // FILTER NOT WORKING.
                inventario.add(cualquiera);
            }
        }
        return inventario;

    }
```

The rest of the class has the getInventario, the getters and setters automatically generated by Eclipse, and the add/remove methods for listaGrande.

Here is the JUnitTestCase.

```
public class FiltraListasTest extends TestCase {

    private FiltraListas checador;
    private Objeto n1;
    private Objeto n2;

    public void testFiltraListas() {
        FiltraListas checa = new FiltraListas("Arranque");
        assertEquals("Arranque", checa.registro);
        assertTrue(checa.listaGrande instanceof ArrayList);
        assertTrue(checa.inventario instanceof ArrayList); // Smooth.

    }
        public void setup() {
        checador = new FiltraListas("Probador"); // Tester.
        checador.addToListaGrande(n1); // Two Objeto on
        checador.addToListaGrande(n2); // right list.
        n1 = new Objeto("Pinzas eléctricas");
        n2 = new Objeto("Multímetro");
        n1.setLoTengo("yes"); // CONFLICTIVE. Should make setInventario to work.
        n2.setLoTengo("Pronto lo compraré"); // I'll buy it soon.

    }

    public void testListaGrande() {
        setup();
        ArrayList<Objeto> todasCosas = checador.getListaGrande();
        ArrayList<Objeto> pruebaInventario = checador.getInventario();
        assertEquals(2, todasCosas.size());
        assertEquals(1, pruebaInventario.size()); // Probes to be wrong.

    }
}
```

This is my implementation of Dan's suggestion. I think should be working. But it is not. Any idea to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, ThiefMaster and Flexo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something of the following?:

```
List<Dice> myInventory = new ArrayList<Dice>();
for (Dice die : bigList) {
    if ("YES".equalsIgnoreCase(die.getHaveIt())) {
        myInventory.add(die);
    }
}
return myInventory;
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Dan, hi. I been trying to implement your code on my program. And there is something I am not doing well. Is it possible that you check what I wrote? I will put some code answering this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If using Apache Commons Collections is an option for you, consider using the [filter](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29) or [select](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#select%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate,%20java.util.Collection%29) method, according to your needs.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks to the three of you for taking time to answer. Sorry I took a long time to respond. It is not easy being brand new in front on tons of information. Andrew, I am still not familiar with Apache Commons, trying to find the answer, I found thenewboston in YouTube. I have been there learning all this days. Is it Apache Commons something you use normally on java programs and android apps? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know about Android apps, but it's not uncommon (get it?) to use Apache Commons libraries (especially commons-lang) in regular Java.

Comment: I found little info about it. Apache Commons for Google and Android it is now under Guava. I'll keep searching.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
public class Dice {

    private static ArrayList<String> myInventory;
    private static String haveIt;

    public void setMyInventory() {
        if (haveIt.equals("Yes") || haveIt.equals("yes"))
            myInventory = new ArrayList<String>();
        else
            myInventory = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jack. I tryed your solution on Eclipse. And I believed it creates an ArrayList, but, does it adds and remove them automatically or another method is needed? I could not make it work. Thanks again.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, to add to/remove from an ArrayList, you just do this: `myInventory.add(String); myInventory.remove(indexOf(String));`